# In Tritium, how do I select an element if I only know its relationship with another element?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I'm using the Moovweb SDK to transform my blog site, and I have a list of comments as such:

```
<ul class="commentlist">
  <li class="comment" id="li-comment-131126">
    <div id="comment-131126">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
        Comment from <cite class="fn" id="tevfik_sertel01">Tevfik Sertel</cite>
      </div>
      <p>I'm so great!</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="comment" id="li-comment-131127">
    <div id="comment-131127">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
        Comment from <cite class="fn" id="jimmy_page01">Jimmy Page</cite>
      </div>
      <p>You're really not that great.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="comment" id="li-comment-131129">
    <div id="comment-131129">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
        Comment from <cite class="fn" id="roger_waters_07">Roger Waters</cite>
      </div>
      <p>You're actually kind of a bore.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Because they're preposterous I want to get rid of all the comments not written by tevfik.

Or rather remove the lis that have cites whose ids don't contain tevfik.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can scope into stuff inside the condition square brackets as such:

```
$(".//li[.//cite[not(contains(@id, 'tevfik'))]]") { 
  remove() 
}
```

Or even simpler, by using the remove() function directly:

```
remove(".//li[.//cite[not(contains(@id, 'tevfik'))]]")
```

Comment: would it be possible to do this w CSS selectors?

Comment: I've created a tritium share for the example:  http://tritium.moovweb.com/81a747baa4b34d5b13c2c5e584f99033eddc7bda

Comment: In this example, it would not be possible because the <li> element is an ancestor of the <cite> element. It is not possible to select parent or ancestors of an element with CSS1-3. You're going to have to wait for future versions of CSS! :)